Why does view not refresh despite @State variable being changed?
Currently I'm having issues refreshing the view in ContentView after clicking a button in EggDeletionConfirmationView. To my understanding, changes to @State variables trigger a refresh of a given view. I've bound the state variable @State refreshContentView in ContentView as a @Binding variable that is passed up to EggDeletionConfirmationView. Despite changing the variable, the view still does not refresh. I've also tried another method by calling the .loadJsonData() function from my viewModel @ObservedObject var viewModel = HabitViewModel() after the button click in EggDeletionConfirmationView. However, the view does not refresh either.
Below I've attached all relevant files.
ContentView
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
extension UIScrollView {  open override var clipsToBounds: Bool {   get { false }   set { }  } }

struct ContentView: View {  
    // State Variables
    @State private var displayState = true
    @State private var displayHabit = " "
    @State private var showAddEggView = false  
    @State private var showSettingsView = false
    @State private var loadJsonData = true
    @State private var refreshContentView = false
    
    // For Array of Habit Structs (loaded on initialization)
    @StateObject var viewModel = HabitViewModel()
            
    // ContentView
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            // Main Chicken
            let chickenImageName = fulfilled == numOfEggs ? "chicken_in_egg" : "chicken_in_egg_sad"
            
            ZStack {
                // ContentView Background
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.9294117647, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tapped Screen")
                        displayHabit = " "
                        print(refreshContentView)
                    }
                
                // Settings Button
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer().frame(maxWidth: 300)
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Settings tapped")
                            showSettingsView = true
                        }) {
                            Image("settings")
                                .resizable()
                                .background(Color.clear)
                                .frame(width: 37, height: 37)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Image(chickenImageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                    
                    // ScrollView
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: -10) {
                            if numOfEggs == 0 {
                                // FIX THIS (when all eggs are removed)
                                //                                HabitEggButton(habit: .constant(Habit(habitName: "Temp"))).opacity(0)
                            } else {
                                
                                if viewModel.isLoading {
                                    Text("Loading data...")
                                }
                                else {
                                    ForEach($viewModel.habits) { $habit in
                                        if habit.isDisplayed {
                                            HabitEggButton(habit: $habit, displayHabit: $displayHabit)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                // Add HabitEgg Button
                                Button(action: {
                                    print("Add tapped")
                                    showAddEggView = true
                                    
                                }) {
                                    Image("add-button")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                        .offset(x: -28, y: 10)
                                        .frame(width: 180, height: 100)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(x: 25)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showAddEggView) {
                        AddEggView(viewModel: viewModel)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsView) {
                        SettingsView(refreshContentView: $refreshContentView, viewModel: viewModel)
                    }
                    
                    // Habit Text Display
                    Text(displayHabit)
                        .font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 26))
                        .opacity(displayHabit == "" ? 0 : 1)
                        .offset(y: 50)
                }
                .offset(y: -65)
            }
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

SettingsView
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var refreshContentView: Bool
    @State private var refreshSettingsView = false
    @State private var inputHabit: String = ""
    @State private var hasPast = true
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : HabitViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.9294117647, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                // Current Eggs
                Text("Current Eggs:").font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 30))
                ScrollView {
                    // Vertical Entry Stack
                    VStack {
                        if viewModel.isLoading {
                            Text("Loading data...")
                        }
                        else {
                            ForEach($viewModel.habits) { $habit in
                                CurrentEggElement(viewModel: viewModel, id: habit.id, habitName: habit.habitName, streakValue: "14", refreshContentView: $refreshContentView, refreshSettingsView: $refreshSettingsView)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.clipped()
                
                
                if (hasPast) {
                    // Past Eggs
                    Text("Past Eggs:").font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 30))
                    ScrollView {
                        // Vertical Entry Stack
                        VStack {
                            if viewModel.isLoading {
                                Text("Loading data...")
                            }
                            else {
                                ForEach($viewModel.pastHabits) { $habit in
                                    PastEggElement(id: $habit.wrappedValue.id, habitName: $habit.wrappedValue.habitName, streakValue: "14")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.clipped()
                }
                
            }.padding(.top, 50)
        }
    }
}


CurrentEggElement
import SwiftUI
struct CurrentEggElement: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : HabitViewModel
    var id: UUID
    var habitName: String
    var streakValue: String
    
    @Binding var refreshContentView: Bool
    @Binding var refreshSettingsView: Bool
    @State private var habitIDString = ""
    @State private var showHabitInfoView = false
    @State private var habitType = ""
    @State private var totalCollected = 0
    @State private var currentStreak = 0
    @State private var started = ""
    @State private var ended = "---"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // Left side content
            HStack {
                // Egg Info Button
                Button(action: {
                    print("Info tapped")
                    print("Data: ")
                    print(self.id)
                    
                    habitIDString = self.id.uuidString
                    habitType = getHabitType(id: self.id)
                    totalCollected = getTotalCollected(id: self.id)
                    currentStreak = getCurrentStreak(id: self.id)
                    started = getStartDate(id: self.id)
                    showHabitInfoView = true
                }) {
                    Image("egg_uncracked")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                
                
                // Habit Egg Text
                Text(habitName).font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 25)).offset(x: -10, y: 5)
                    .fixedSize()
            }.offset(x: 25)
            
            Spacer()
            
            // Right side content
            HStack {
                // Streak Button
                Button(action: {
                    print("Streak tapped")
                    
                }) {
                    Image("fire")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                
                // Streak Text
                Text(streakValue + " d").font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 25)).fixedSize().offset(y: -2)
            }.offset(x: -35, y: 5)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showHabitInfoView) {
            HabitInfoView(viewModel: viewModel,
                          refreshContentView: $refreshContentView, refreshSettingsView: $refreshSettingsView, showHabitInfoView: $showHabitInfoView, habitIDString: $habitIDString,
                          habitType: $habitType,
                          totalCollected: $totalCollected,
                          currentStreak: $currentStreak,
                          started: $started,
                          ended: $ended)
        }
    }
}

func getTotalCollected(id: UUID) -> Int {
    do {
        if let jsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "currentHabitData.json") {
            let habits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: jsonData)
            print("Successfully decoded habits: \(habits)")
            
            if let habit = habits.first(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                print("Total collected for habit with id \(id): \(habit.totalCollected)")
                
                return habit.totalCollected
                
            } else {
                print("Habit with id not found")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get JSON data")
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
    
    return -1
}

func getCurrentStreak(id: UUID) -> Int {
    do {
        if let jsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "currentHabitData.json") {
            let habits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: jsonData)
            print("Successfully decoded habits: \(habits)")
            
            if let habit = habits.first(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                let totalCollected = habit.totalCollected
                print("Streak for habit with id \(id): \(totalCollected)")
                return habit.streak
                
            } else {
                print("Habit with id not found")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get JSON data")
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
    
    return -1
}

func getStartDate(id: UUID) -> String {
    do {
        if let jsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "currentHabitData.json") {
            let habits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: jsonData)
            print("Successfully decoded habits: \(habits)")
            
            if let habit = habits.first(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                let startDate = habit.startDate
                print("Start Date for habit with id \(id): \(startDate)")
                return habit.startDate
                
            } else {
                print("Habit with id not found")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get JSON data")
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
    
    return "NIL"
}

func getHabitType(id: UUID) -> String {
    do {
        if let jsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "currentHabitData.json") {
            let habits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: jsonData)
            print("Successfully decoded habits: \(habits)")
            
            if let habit = habits.first(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                let habitType = habit.habitType
                print("Habit type for habit with id \(id): \(habitType)")
                return habit.habitType
                
            } else {
                print("Habit with id not found")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get JSON data")
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
    
    return "NIL"
}

EggDeletionView
import SwiftUI

struct EggDeletionConfirmationView: View {
    @Binding var showConfirmation: Bool
    @Binding var habitIDString : String
    @Binding var showHabitInfoView : Bool
    @Binding var refreshContentView: Bool
    @Binding var refreshSettingsView: Bool
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : HabitViewModel

    let title: String
    let message: String
    let buttonTitle: String
    let action: () -> ()
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 1000

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.black)
                .opacity(0.5)
                .onTapGesture {
                    close()
                }

            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .padding()

                Text(message)
                    .font(.body)

                Button {
                    action()
                    close()
                    showHabitInfoView = false
                    refreshContentView = true
                    refreshSettingsView = true
                    viewModel.loadJsonData()
                    
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)

                        Text(buttonTitle)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .padding()
            .background(.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Button {
                    close()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                }
                .tint(.black)
                .padding()
            }
            .shadow(radius: 20)
            .padding(30)
            .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
            .onChange(of: showConfirmation, initial: true) {
                print(habitIDString)
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    offset = 0
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }

    func close() {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            offset = 1000
            showConfirmation = false
        }
    }
}


ContentViewModel
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class HabitViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var habits: [Habit] = []
    @Published var pastHabits: [Habit] = []
    @Published var isLoading = true
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    
    init() {
        loadJsonData()
    }
    
    func loadJsonData() {
        print("HABITS ARE:")
        print(habits)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            // loads data from currentHabitData.json
            if let currentHabitJsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "currentHabitData.json") {
                do {
                    let habits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: currentHabitJsonData)
                                        
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.habits = habits
                        self.isLoading = false
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorMessage = "Error decoding JSON data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                        self.isLoading = false
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve JSON data"
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
            
            // loads data from pastHabitData.json
            if let pastHabitJsonData = getJsonData(fileName: "pastHabitData.json") {
                do {
                    let pastHabits = try JSONDecoder().decode([Habit].self, from: pastHabitJsonData)
                                        
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.pastHabits = pastHabits
                        self.isLoading = false
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorMessage = "Error decoding JSON data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                        self.isLoading = false
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve JSON data"
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Habit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct Habit : Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var habitName: String
    var isDisplayed = true
    var habitType: String
    var totalCollected: Int
    var streak: Int
    var startDate: String
}

I've confirmed that the state binding variable is being changed from false to true, but that still does not update the view. I've also attempted to call my function loadJsonData() on my viewModel which should've altered one of the member variables to trigger a reload of the view, but it doesn't. Any help would be great, thank you!

You should have only one source of truth data model. In your ContentView use
@StateObject var viewModel = HabitViewModel(), pass this model to all
other views. Currently you have multiple HabitViewModel (eg SettingsView)
that have no relation to each other.

See Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

Note, your understanding changes to @State variables trigger a refresh of a given view. is not complete.
From the State docs,
"When the value changes, SwiftUI updates the parts of the view hierarchy that depend on the value."
Your ContentView does not seem to depend on refreshContentView.
Regarding the .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsView), you should consider using .sheet(item: ...) instead.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Ty! I've made the changes you suggested and passed the StateObject HabitViewModel to the other views using ObservedObject var viewModel : HabitViewModel when accessing different views. However, the view still doesn't reset when data is deleted. Currently, my custom button "CurrentEggElement" requires an initialization of viewModel in its constructor, which I've done with self.viewModel = viewModel. I was wondering if this would be the right way of initializing and using the same viewModel passed up by ContentView, or if there are any other ideas refreshing the view

@workingdogsupportUkraine Also, I'm a little confused about ContentView not depending on refreshContentVIew. I changed the code a little by making the views only display if refreshContentView was true, but doing so did not refresh the view in ContentView when the value of refreshContentView was changed. This change would make the view depend on the value, but why doesn't that trigger a refresh of the view?

Could you update your post with the code you are using now. It is becoming difficult to guess what you have changed?

@workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, I've just updated the post with the new code! I mainly changed the viewModel to be @StateObject var viewModel = HabitViewModel() in ContentView and @ObservedObject var viewModel : HabitViewModel in the other views. Let me know if there's anything else I could post, thank you for your help again!

Note, in SettingsView you should have
CurrentEggElement(viewModel: viewModel, id: ...).
Why do you have $habit.wrappedValue.id, can you show
the code for Habit, it should be a struct and you should pass it like habit.id etc...
Note also, in your CurrentEggElement you should have
@ObservedObject var viewModel: HabitViewModel first, then
var id: UUID etc... to match the call sequence, and without
using $ and wrappedValue for habit.
Also there is no need for those custom init(...), remove them. Also NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you! I've implemented the mentioned changes. However, the view refresh issue still persists. I've edited the post and attached the code for my Habit file.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I've figured it out. Turns out the view was refreshing correctly, however in the HabitViewModel json file there was no check in the case that the file was empty, and thus didn't change the viewModel which didn't trigger a re-render. Thank you for your help you helped me understand a lot more about Swift and SwiftUI I really appreciate it!

@State only calls body when set if its getter has previously been called. If you aren't calling the getter then it means the State is wrong or is defined at the wrong level in the hierarchy.
Another thing I noticed is you shouldn't have view model objects since the View structs are the view model already. However it seems to me your object is actually the model store, usually that is a singleton injected into the Environment so it can be swapped out for the test data object for Previews, e.g. .environmentObject(ModelStore.shared or ModelStore.test)
You shouldn't have @State bools like refreshView, showHabitInfoView etc. you need to get your the types of your State correct. It can be a bit tricky to think like this but basically rather than think "I need to set this bool" to refresh or show this thing, you just set the State for the thing you want to show. E.g. if you want to edit something then make a State for that thing and then set it, e.g.
@State var newThing: Thing?

...

.sheet(item: $newThing) {

}

This assumes the newThing is temp view data and will be saved somewhere else. But the real power of SwiftUI is you can bind right into your model data.
Usually people are familiar with computed vars to transform their model data into View inits, but you can also transform bindings too. This allows your model's property type to be different from the type of the various UI controls.
